# How to solve the logical expression?

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

We have the logical expression:

```
p AND (p OR q) AND NOT (NOT p AND p)
```

What will be the end result of this expression?

How to solve it? From what I remember from University. But how to present the answer? In my case I think it is just **p**. But what if there are 1101 or other strange result how to present it as answer?

[image]

Comment: `NOT p AND p` is always false, so `NOT (NOT p AND p)` is always true, so the `AND` is redundant, so you’re left with `p AND (p OR q)`. `p OR q` is always true if `p` is true, so `p AND (p OR q)` simplifies to `p`. If that’s what you’re asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression you've given, if `p` is `true`, then the expression evaluates to `true`. Otherwise, if `p` is `false`, then the expression evaluates to `false`.

If we break down your expression starting from the ride-hand side:

```
NOT (NOT p AND p) is always true
```

Thus, the expression you gave is equivalent to:

```
p AND (p OR q)
```

For any `true` value of `p`, the expression `p AND (p OR q)` is true:

```
true AND (true or q) == true
```

For any `false` value of `p`, the expression `p AND (p OR q)` is false:

```
false AND (false or q) == false
```

Thus, the given expression `p AND (p OR q) AND NOT (NOT p AND p)` is entirely dependent on `p`.

Comment: Can you give some more explanations

Answer (score 1):

If you need to write a code for solving such expressions, use some parser generator like [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/) or similar. It will convert the expression into data tree that will be easy to evaluate using recursion or even on the fly while  being parsed.

If you just need to solve this one expression, see the comment on your question, it is an answer. The expression evaluates to `p`.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct. You can also derive it by a series of transformations (for example, you could observe that `NOT p AND p` is always false, etc).

> But what if there are 1101 or other strange result how to present it as answer?

You could present it as the truth table or by showing the [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) (or conjuctive normal form). The normal forms are easy to construct from the truth table.